# how to check for a special character "<" or ">" in a input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to check for < or > in the user input in javascript.
any idea what the regular expression wud be?
This regex does not seem to work

```
 var spclChar=/^[<>]$/;
        if(searchCriteria.firstName.match(spclChar)){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: How are you using it? Where is your code?

Comment: [`/[<>]/`](https://regex101.com/r/oP0nG0/1)

Comment: your regex is searching for a `<` at the START of the string, or a `>` at the END of the string. if you want them ANYWHERE in the string, then dump the `^` and `$`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/945968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class like this:

```
[<>]
or
[><]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/hS3qW9/1)**

Btw, you have useful comments in your question like **[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703229/sam)**'s

> /[<>]/
>
> https://regex101.com/r/oP0nG0/1

and **[Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)**'s

> your regex is searching for a < at the START of the string, or a > at the END of the string. if you want them ANYWHERE in the string, then dump the ^ and $. –  Marc B 7 mins ago

Comment: Thanks for converting the lazy into an answer ;)

Comment: @Sam lol. Feel free to create the answer if you want, I can update mine as well.

Comment: Nah, I don't mind. I was being serious when I said thanks. You cited both of us, so this just makes SO better for people stumbling on this question.

Comment: @Bidisha glad to help